# IIS 10 network share

Tags: iis

I have windows server 2016 IIS 10 installed which is running asp.net application, when the website is in local path it works fine but as soon as i change the physical path to network share it stopped working i get 500.19 error when path is F:/share (F drive is Mapped drive), and i get 401.3 Unauthorized error when path is \UNCpath\Share.

The Shared drive is coming from Server 2016 File Server

I have tried all type of permission change Application pool identity, connect as but none of them work

can someone please help what type of permission needed on shared folder, all the Servers are in domain network

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-most-common-technologies-not-supported-by-microsoft-8675c409bde2 Mapped drives are not supported.

Comment: Yes but you can still use UNC path